# In-process Workflow: Lotus Notes to SharePoint Migration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow, migration, lotus-notes

I have a question how about in-process workflow

I migrated workflow application (approval workflow) from Lotus Notes to SharePoint 2007 by using Quest tool.

I migrated workflow by hand (dev) and list item data by using Quest. But I wonder how can I migrate in-process workflows that can be run continuously after migrating. How can I ensured that some item in-process can run normally, participants of the workflow can also migrated with the workflow after migrating?

Btw, Is there any sample workflow (*.NFS) you can share for test these solutions?

Many Thanks & Regards!

Comment: Please share some best practices for the problems like that.

Answer (score 0):

Workflow itself is not a part of built-in Notes functionality. It is always built using third-party solutions or add-on like Lotus Workflow which is *not* part of Lotus Notes/Domino. But anyhow it doesn't seem to be possible for placing SharePoint list item or document in the middle of the flow as you want it. Let all running flows finish on Notes and migrate the historical data.